# Transparancy/color gradient not displayed in every PDF viewer

Tags: color, pdf, gradient

For my CV I used headlines with color gradients. Now I recently discovered that the headlines are not displayed in some PDF viewers (e.g. the gmail preview of an pdf).
On my Mac in the Preview App or in Adobe Reader everything looks as it should.

The color gradient I produced with the following code in LaTeX:

```
\definecolor{right}{HTML}{2472AF} %defines the color for the timeline
\definecolor{left2}{HTML}{0d2d47} %defines the color of the left side of the section headings


\makeatletter

\renewcommand\section[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\randref{rand}
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikzsection \randref]
    \node[fill=white,anchor=south east,zero sep,minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=2.5mm] (box node){};
    \node [text=white,anchor=base west,text depth=5pt,text height=12pt,zero sep,
    font=\normalfont\Large\bfseries,right=10pt of box node,
    text width=13cm,align=left] (text node) {\strut#1\strut};
    \node [fit={(box node)(text node)
      },zero sep] (myfit) {};
    \path let \p1=(myfit.south west), \p2=(myfit.north east), \n1={\x2-\x1}, \n2={\y2-\y1} in
    \pgfextra{\xdef\lenx{\n1} \xdef\leny{\n2}};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=.5*5pt-.5*12pt]
      \path[path fading=tikzsection \randref, fit fading=false,left color=left2, right color=right]
      (-.5*\lenx,-.5*\leny) rectangle ++(\lenx,\leny);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \par\nobreak\addvspace{1ex}\@afterheading%
}
```

This are the two outputs as it is supposed to be and in the gmail Preview not displaying the headlines (apparently also other PDF viewers don't display it as my girlfriend using the same CV layout walked into an interview where the HR people had her CV printed without all of the headlines):

[image: Adobe Reader with headlines]

[image: Gmail Preview without headlines]

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro in case that helps to fix this problem. How can I embed this color gradients in my output PDF so it is displayed everywhere properly?

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with transparency is a very complex task for a PDF viewer, and there are many viewers which simply don't do it (or don't do it properly).

Fortunately, when it comes to transparency, you can do something, namely flatten them. In the Print Production tools in Acrobat Pro, there is the Flattener Preview, where you can flatten the transparencies (which means that the part of the document which is covered by an object with transparency will be rendered as raster image). In that tool you have the controls to set the type and quality of rasterizing, and you have other maybe useful controls as well (such as turning text into outlines).

After applying this tool, your users should see what you want them to see.