# Why is my TikZ fill command (using foreach) not shown correctly by all PDF viewers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf

When I use a foreach in a `fill` (or `draw`) command, the resulting PDF appears only in some PDF Viewers (VS Code, Firefox) but not in others (MS Edge, Google Drive, Dropbox).

Here's a minimal piece of code to replicate this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ticks = none,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        xmin=-3,
        xmax=10,
        ymin=-4, 
        ymax=4]

        \addplot [
            domain=0:5, 
            samples=100, 
            color=blue
        ]{sqrt(x)};
        \addplot [
            domain=5:6, 
            samples=100, 
            color=blue,
            dashed
        ]{sqrt(x)};

        \fill [fill=green,
                fill opacity=0.2]
            (-3,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,-4) -- (-3,-4) -- cycle;

        \fill [fill=blue,
                fill opacity=0.2] 
            foreach \x in {0, 0.1, ..., 5}
            { -- ({\x}, {sqrt(\x)}) }
            -- (4,0) -- cycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and a screenshot of VS Code and Edge side by side with the same file opened:
[image: PDF result of the code above]

Is there a way to solve this? Or do I have to manually write all the coordinates for the fill?

P.S. This is not a duplicate of [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268846/transparancy-color-gradient-not-displayed-in-every-pdf-viewer), since the green fill is displayed normally despite having opacity=0.2.

Comment: your code is not complete and so can't be compiled and tested. And should mention which engine you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the start coordinate:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ticks = none,
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        xmin=-3,
        xmax=10,
        ymin=-4, 
        ymax=4]

        \addplot [
            domain=0:5, 
            samples=100, 
            color=blue
        ]{sqrt(x)};
        \addplot [
            domain=5:6, 
            samples=100, 
            color=blue,
            dashed
        ]{sqrt(x)};

        \fill [fill=green,
                fill opacity=0.2]
            (-3,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,-4) -- (-3,-4) -- cycle;

        \fill [fill=blue,
                fill opacity=0.2] 
            (0,0) %<--- missing
            foreach \x in {0, 0.1, ..., 5}
            { -- ({\x}, {sqrt(\x)}) }
            -- (4,0) -- cycle;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see. I feel very stupid, thank you so much.